# What types of responces exists that return media file (image, video and other), and when they are used

Tags: http, get, request

I am sorry if the question is stupid, but I am not sure if I know all the types of http GET responses, that can contain image. There is response that returns the image as attachment, and other one that returns the image as static file. Are there other variation to return image(or other media) and when they are used?

Comment: It really comes down to the acceptable content the request advertises with the HTTP header [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept), which addresses content negotiation.  For example the server might implement a proprietary content delivery format.  This is just one of the many excellent facets of REST.

Comment: There is Content-Disposition header that seems to be also important for how the browser reacts to the media file. If this header is set to 'inline' then the browser tries to open the file within. Having this header set to 'attachment' makes the browser to download the file.